# ContentResolver - run delete query in transaction

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I delete a single image like following:

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(image.getImageUri(), null, null);
```

The problem is, the deleting in the `ContentResolver` is quite slow. Can i somehow summurize the deletes in a transaction?

**Edit**

I'm deleting images from the media store

Comment: If you wrote the provider you can add the transaction in the delete method otherwise you're out of luck.

Comment: I added some info about the provider. I'm selecting images from the media store so this means all I can do is do the job in the background as it's to slow to wait for the result...

Answer (score 0):

Hey prom85 I am not sure how exactly you can speed up a single delete but if your need to batch several deletes in a transaction here is a bulk delete method from a content provider I wrote.Hope it helps :) !

```
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (match) {
            case MOVIE:
                db.beginTransaction();
                int returnCount = 0;
                try {
                    for (ContentValues value : values) {
                        long _id = db.insert(MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, value);
                        if (_id != -1) {
                            returnCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                } finally {
                    db.endTransaction();
                }
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                return returnCount;
            case REVIEW:
                db.beginTransaction();
                int returnCountReview = 0;
                try {
                    for (ContentValues value : values) {
                        long _id = db.insert(MovieContract.ReviewEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, value);
                        if (_id != -1) {
                            returnCountReview++;
                        }
                    }
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                } finally {
                    db.endTransaction();
                }
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                return returnCountReview;
            case TRAILER:
                db.beginTransaction();
                int returnCountTrailer = 0;
                try {
                    for (ContentValues value : values) {
                        long _id = db.insert(MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, value);
                        if (_id != -1) {
                            returnCountTrailer++;
                        }
                    }
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                } finally {
                    db.endTransaction();
                }
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                return returnCountTrailer;
            default:
                return super.bulkInsert(uri, values);
        }
    }
```